# get client ip and client location in symfony2

Tags: symfony, ip

I need the client IP address to find the client location so that I could list the details of that area to he client. I used this code to find the IP address.

> $this->container->get('request')->getClientIp();

But I'm getting the IP as **127.0.0.1.**

How can I get the client IP address? Can someone give me a complete working code?

Comment: I also tried this code.

$this->container->get('request')->server->get("REMOTE_ADDR");

Still the same result as above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **127.0.0.1** because your server is installed on your machine (I guess).
But `$request->getClientIp()` is the right way to get the user ip.

For the geolocation, I suggest you to take a look at the [geocoder](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder) library and [his bundle](https://github.com/geocoder-php/BazingaGeocoderBundle).

Comment: i hosted the code in server and got it right. thanks

Comment: I was unable to get the expected result. I was getting "127.0.0.1" as output from $this->container->get('request')->getClientIp();

And the proper ip using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].
So I had to use  $_SERVER. Can you please get me this resolved with getClientIp???
Please note that I am using symfony 2.2

Comment: @AshishShah running the code in localhost will return only 127.0.0.1. host it in some server. it will word fine

Comment: I run the code on my live site and getting 127.0.0.1 as output from $this->container->get('request')->getClientIp(); And RIGHT IP using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].